# Read asp.net link button text from server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, asplinkbutton

net page with two controls

1. linkbutton
2. button

While running my application, I'm changing my link button text using javascript function.

Now I want to read that text when I press button. Button event is there in server side.

When I try to read like below

```
string s = linkButton.Text;
```

It is not giving my updated text.

How can I get it?

Comment: Please add your server side and .aspx markup

Comment: protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string s = linkButton.Text;
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, declare this `HiddenField` in your markup

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="link" runat="server" />
```

Then in the function, you change the link button text, you should add the following code, in order the new text to the `HiddenField` been added.

```
document.getElementById(<%=link.ClientID%>).setAttribute("Value",newText);
```

Last, in your server side code you can get the value you want with the following way:

```
string s = link.Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `HiddenField`.

The `LinkButton` does not implement [`IPostBackDataHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackdatahandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), therefore it doesn't load postback data.

You can write the `HiddenField.Value` on client- and read it on serverside.

Here's a tutorial-video: [[How Do I:] Use a Hidden Field to Store and Manipulate Client-Side Information](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-use-a-hidden-field-to-store-and-manipulate-client-side-information)